# Float to fixed length string

Tags: java, floating-point, string-formatting

I was trying to convert float value to a fixed length string. I got an unexpected output when the format is greater than `%.6`. Sample code and output are below,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a=10.9f; 
        System.out.println(String.format("%07.2f", a)); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%09.4f", a)); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%011.6f", a)); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%012.7f", a)); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%013.8f", a));   
    }

}
```

Output

```
0010.90
0010.9000
0010.900000
0010.8999996
0010.89999962
```

Why am I getting 8999996 & 89999962 instead of 9000000 & 90000000?

Comment: Read the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1)

Comment: [Secret Robot Internet](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2999).